# Calling shutDownHook for certain exit codes?

Tags: java, shutdown-hook

As far as I know System.exit triggers shutdown hook(if any hook registered) so  while shutdown hook thread is waiting  for any other thread to join 
if other thread calls System.exit()  I think a deadlock  occurs so is there any solution to register a shutdown hook for certain exit codes such as -1?
By this way I can prevent a shutdown hook not to work for some specials  exit situations.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine exit status within the java shutdown hook thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486679/determine-exit-status-within-the-java-shutdown-hook-thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shutdown hook mechanism doesn't have any way to run shutdown hooks just for particular exit codes. You could register a shutdown hook which checks the exit code, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486679/determine-exit-status-within-the-java-shutdown-hook-thread), and decides what to do based on that.