# execute task only on ctrl^C (Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thead t) )

Tags: java, jvm, runtime, shutdown, application-shutdown

I'm developing a project which has complete java code & SQL, where the application kicks-off from the shell script. 
I want to execute some cleanup task (closing transactions n logging abrupt message) when a user press Ctrl^C.

I tried with adding shut down task by 
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread)

But it'll execute every time my application is exits the VM & i never know is that command killed / executed successfully.

I'm looking for some pointers to implement this.

- Thanks in Advance..!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486679/determine-exit-status-within-the-java-shutdown-hook-thread may help.

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you override the SecurityManager checkExit(int status) method.
But this is not a recommended way of handling this sort of event. 
If my code experience ctrl+c, I usually like to do clean up when I see something inconsistent next time. This is usually not a bad idea.

Comment: The application db can be used in some other places, where i'll get the stale data (In my application perspective). I'm trying to avoid that & log some messages against those objects. So on exit only i should do these tasks.

Comment: @anji_rajesh sounds like you have to make sure your DB operation is more atomic. Rather than multiple steps which can cause stale data.